# calling rest ful web service in java using a given end point which takes xml as an put?

Tags: java, web-services, spring, restful-architecture

I am new to webservices. i am working on a project. i am asked to call a rest ful webservice which takes xml as in put. below is the end point.

```
https://api-something.com/someLocation/status
```

HTTP method is `POST`

How can i pass the xml and call the above end point in Java/spring?

How to pass an `XML` file as an input to the specified end point?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use Spring, please take a look at Spring Data REST
http://www.springsource.org/spring-data/rest#documentation

Here you will find your answer.

Please note that you can also take a look at Jersey (JAX-RS, Java EE standard):
http://www.vogella.com/articles/REST/article.html

Answer (score 0):

If you're writing integration tests then take a look at [rest-assured](http://code.google.com/p/rest-assured/) (very easy to use library for rest testing) and it's [XML example](http://code.google.com/p/rest-assured/wiki/Usage#Example_2_-_XML)

If you're writing production code take look at [RestTemplate](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/RestTemplate.html) (it is a spring component)